# Why isn't this simple Bootstrap Confirmation working?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn how to use Bootstrap-Confirmation.js.org to make a simple "Are you sure?" popup happen on a link like in the "On a link" example here:

https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/#installation

I copied what I think are the necessary parts of the sample to an index.html file, but the pop up doesn't happen for me.

I'm new at this, so I'm probably missing something simple.

What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Confirmation Example</title>

  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.3.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/assets/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bs-example">
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Open Google?"
       href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Confirmation</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting? Please attach error.

Comment: Looks like you did not include all of the libraries needed. Where is the reference to popper?

Comment: @AbuSufian I'm using Firefox (77.0.1) with Web Console visible and there is no error displayed.

Comment: @AndySummers2020 you want a modal where there will be Yes or No and if Yes then it will go to https://google.com . Is this what you want right? for modal you need help of little bit JS.

Comment: @AbuSufian Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to use this 'bootstrap-confirmation' library instead of writing a modal with JS because the UI is better for my application.  You can see the demo at the link I provided, go down to the "On a link" section and click the 'Confirmation' button to see it.